# How to access HTTP GET/POST API in Qt/C++

Tags: php, c++, mysql, qt

I have a MySQL database with a PHP scripts written to exploit the database. I'm writing a program in C++ and want to access the PHP classes to power the application.
How should I go about doing this?

If I have a PHP function I want to get a return value from, how do I do this in C++? Is it even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a PHP script from a C++ Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470448/calling-a-php-script-from-a-c-program)

Comment: Use HTTP POST and GET methods. Libcurl would be my suggestion.

Comment: When using the PHP API inside a PHP script, I used cURL. Is it a similar process?

Comment: @kingkero - the duplicate you claim isn't relevant as I'm after a more specific way to use get and post http headers...

Comment: HTTP with Qt: QNetworkAccessManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is a general one for C++. If you are using Qt then I would suggest `QNetworkAccessManager` class. It has functions `get` and `post` to handle HTTP GET/POST request.

Comment: Ahhh perfect! So I could use those functions to interact with the PHP API using get and post :) that's the question answered right there!